# I want to convert a number from 1 - 15 into a 4 bit binary number

Tags: vb.net, binary

I have got this code so far:

```
    Dim Binary_representation As String
    Dim random_number As Integer
    Dim lower As Integer = 1
    Dim upper As Integer = 15

    Randomize()
    random_number = CInt(Math.Floor((upper - lower + 1) * Rnd())) + lower

    BinaryNumber.Text = random_number

    Binary_representation = Convert.ToString(random_number, 2)

    BinaryNumber2.Text = Binary_representation
```

It is good and converts the number to binary but when for example the random number generates 3, it will convert the number into a 2 bit binary number, any ideas on how to get 0011 instead of 11 when the random number is for example 3.

Have an idea that adding 0s onto the front, when it is only 1 character add 3 0's, 2 characters, 2 0's and 3 characters 1 0. How could i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
Dim r as New Random()
BinaryNumber2.Text = Convert.ToString(r.Next(1,16), 2).PadLeft(4, "0"c)
```

Yep; just two lines. Could chop it to one if you want:

```
BinaryNumber2.Text = Convert.ToString(New Random().Next(1,16), 2).PadLeft(4, "0"c)
```

The operations here are:

- `Convert.ToString(number, toBase)` - only of limited use as toBase must be 2, 8, 10 or 16, but works for this
- `New Random().Next(1, 16)` - makes a new random number generator, seeded from the system clock, and calls Next which returns a number between 1 and "less than 16" ie 15. Do not use New Random inside a loop; it will run so fast that hundreds of new randoms will get the same seed value time and produce identical numbers. Make one instance of random outside a loop and call Next inside the loop
- `PadLeft(4, '0')` - because Convert.ToString doesn't put leading zeros

Comment: Thanks, amazing how it can be on one line! :)